# socketio server doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am having this  in my server.js file

```
var app = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var server = app();
server.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    }
);

server.listen(81);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(82);;


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone'});

  socket.on('private message', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);
    io.emit('done','done from server');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.sockets.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

It works fine locally but when I deploy it to my website and try to connect on it from the server it always time out giving me this error

I have a javascript client like this one

```
var socket = io.connect('ws://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.net:82/');
```

and It always give me that error

```
GET http://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.net:82/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1403458443180-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT socket.io-1.0.0-pre5.js:2
```

can someone help me and let me know why it always timeout?

Comment: It looks like firewall is blocking `82` port. You may try proxying from `80` to `82`

Comment: @CuriousGuy the same happened with 80 and 3000, It's not the port